# How do I take the same index of different lists and put it into seperate lists?

Tags: python, list

Consider lists

```
a=[1,2,5,4,3]
b=[2,4,8,3,4]
```

I want my final lists to be

```
c=[1,2] d=[2,4] e=[5,8] f=[4,3] g=[3,4]
```

Comment: Use `list(zip(*iterables))` here

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a for loop:

```
result = []

for t in zip(a, b):
    result.append(list(t))

result
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 4], [5, 8], [4, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`.

```
my_new_lists = list(map(list, zip(a,b)))
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. I got it. But can i do the same using a for loop and how ?